# Automatic library download in Eclipse with Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, build, gradle, libraries

I'm developing an java application. I'm using eclipse Luna and Gradle as my build-system. I can define dependencies in my build script and they get downloaded on a build. That's no problem... But how can I tell eclipse, that it should automatically download and add the dependency to my build path?

I wan't to use auto completion and so on, without manually downloading an jar and copy it to the project.

Is it possible?

Regards
Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [Eclipse Gradle tooling](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/), which adds lots of Gradle-related functionality. Most importantly, it manages your Eclipse project build path to match the `build.gradle` dependencies.